# Can Bullet handle fluids?

Tags: bulletphysics, bullet

`PhysX FleX` is cool. But I prefer `Bullet`. However, I couldn't find any similar features there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:**
OP (Milo Lu) has finally asked it in Bullet's forum and get [a better answer](http://www.bulletphysics.org/Bullet/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=11510&sid=39f98b432e45d05fddc6178851fc2c05) from developer team.

Here is the most useful part from **benelot**:-

> Bullet does not have any fluid features yet except if you can handle
>   it with softbodies (but that would be a very coarse approximation). I
>   once had the feeling that Erwin Coumans was intending to integrate a
>   fluids library into Bullet, look here:
>   https://github.com/erwincoumans/fluids_v3

My original answer (below) is kept for historical reason ...

---

As far as I know, there is no direct feature in Bullet.

The last time it was proposed is 2014, you can track the feature [here](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues/100).

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/features/) (an open-source 3D-modelling and rendering program) can do some of fluid simulation
(search for "Amazing Simulations" in the linked page).

It uses Bullet.

Here is the page to usage of [such feature in blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/domain.html#fluid-boundary).
Digging into its source may disclose some valuable information.
As far as I know, its fluid simulation is not real-time though.

Meanwhile, I suggest simulating fluid as sphere particles (using `btsphereshape`).
I accept that it is not a perfect solution,
but I think it is computationally cheaper and very easy to implement.